# Google+ sharing using Android application

Tags: android

Need to share our application in all social site like Facebook,Twitter,google+ ..Using Share auth api we can share in Facebook and Twitter.

Share Auth API:
http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/wiki/GettingStarted

Not able to share in google+ ,is there any plugin available?

Now am using this sample program,not able to share using this.

https://github.com/imellon/Google-Plus-Android-Sample

Please help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google plus does not have a publicly available API yet although there are some options available at https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/

I would highly recommend not to use a unique SDK for each social network since they contain a lot of bugs, and are not very reliable.

If you just want to share simple text from your app to Facebook,Twitter,Google+ and so on... I would recommend to create a chooser to let the user pick which app from his phone he wants to user for sharing. It is simple, reliable and this is how it's usually done in android.

Sample code  :

```
        Intent shareIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"your text here");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "post title");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share..."));
```

This will display to the user, all the apps that are capable of sharing a text post. If the user has facebook, twitter and google+ apps in his/her phone, then it will show all of them and the user can choose which ones to share to.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for [Google plus sdk for android](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started).

[Sign in](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in)
[Sharing](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/share)
[Write moments to your user's Google+ history](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/write-moments)
[+1 content in your app](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/recommend)